# Active admin customisation ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm new to active admin gem.
My requirement is like admin should be able to view the table as usual. In addition to that there should be a Text box along with a button which can be used for some action.
See the Uploaded Picture Below..[image]

I have a model named PushNotification now and the fields it do have are enabled, rule_name,day_limit,message.

All these values should be shown as in the picture. In addition to that I want a message box with button(send push notification) as shown in picture.

Is this possible in active admin?. If so please do help..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your admin page.

```
    ActiveAdmin.register_page "Push Notification" do
      menu  priority: 12
        action_item do
        link_to "Create New Rule", "/"
        end

     content do
      render partial: 'send_notification'
      end
    end
```

and make a view inside view/admin.

now you can create your custom view in that html page inside admin folder.

Comment: @user2916075 what's the point of creating a new "action item"?    Since you'll be including a Partial form containing the Push Notif. Form anyway.